# Bind JSON object to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding

I want to bind a JSON object to a HTML element.

e.g.

I have a object "person" with the attributes "firstName", "lastName"

```
<div class="person-list">
  <div class="person-list-item">
    <div>John</div>    ---> bind it to person.firstName
    <div>Smith</div>   ---> bind it to person.lastName
  </div>
</div>
```

so, if a value of the HTML elements gets changed, then will also the object person gets updated.

is this possible in any way?

i use:

- jquery
- ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: and how do your expect the html element to be changed? and why that the thing changing your html element can update the json simultaneously too??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you'll be doing this a lot in your application, you may want to bring in a library such as the excellent [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) which uses MVVM to do bindings as you describe.

Your markup would look something like this:

```
<div data-bind="text: firstName"></div>
<div data-bind="text: lastName"></div>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "John";
    this.lastName = "Smith";
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

You can also use a data set if there are many "people."  Try out this tutorial if you would like to learn how to do that: [Working with Lists and Collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections).

**Other useful links:**

- [Introduction tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro)
- [Excellent demo video (about 30 minutes)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08)

Answer (score 3):

First, add `id` attributes to your markup (you could do this with the DOM but for clarity's sake `id`s are probably best suited for this example):

```
<div class="person-list-item">
   <div id="firstname">John</div>
   <div id="lastname">Smith</div>
</div>
```

Use a jQuery event handler to update the fields whenever they are modified (this is an inefficient solution but gets the job done- worry about optimizing once you have something functional):

```
// declare your object
function person(firstn, lastn) {
    this.firstname = firstn;
    this.lastname = lastn;
}

var myGuy = new person("John", "Smith");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#firstname").change(function () {
        myGuy.firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    });

    $("#lastname").change(function () {
        myGuy.lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    });

    // etc...
});
```

Now every time the fields are updated your object will be too.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the JSON to turn it into a JavaScript object:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(json_string);
// or without jQuery:
var data = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

If I understood your question correctly, you should have JSON that look like this:

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Another",
        "lastName": "Person"
    } // etc
]
```

So you can just loop through the people like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = '[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Another","lastName": "Person"}]',
        data = $.parseJSON(str);
    $.each(data, function() {
        var html = '<div class="person-list-item"><div>' + this.firstName + '</div><div>' + this.lastName + '</div></div>';
        $('#person-list').append(html);
     });
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RgdhX/2/

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-way approach using jquery...

```
    var resp = your_json_data;
    $(function () {
        $(".jsondata").each(function () {
            $(this).html(eval($(this).attr("data")));
        });
    });
```

then in the page...

```
 <span class="jsondata" data="resp.result.formatted_phone_number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).  Setting up data binding like you are looking for is very straightforward with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the MVC/MVVM libereries such is [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) or [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).