# How to bind json object in Html page?

Tags: javascript

I want to develop a code which can take json object from the json file and bind it to Html page using java code .I have searched through browser i dint get the solution.Please give me suggestion to solve this issue.

I have the json file.

```
{

    "policyN": "D800026158",
    "policyStartDate": "23-Nov-2017",
    "policyEndDate": "22-Nov-2018",
    "policyIssueDate": "23-Nov-2017",
    "agent": {
        "agentCode": "100006767676702",
        "agentName": "ZInsurance Limited",
        "agentEmail": "hey@gmail.com"
    }   
}
```

If i select PolicyN i should get all the informatiom which is having in json file.

I have tried by using this code

```
PojoMobile myObjects = mapper.readValue(new File("D:/godigit_doc/MobileJsonNew.json"), PojoMobile.class);

System.out.println(".=agentCode=."+myObjects.getAgent().getAgentCode());
System.out.println(".=agentEmail=."+myObjects.getAgent().getAgentEmail());
```

Pojo class is :

```
public class PojoMobile {

    private String policyNumber;

    private String policyStartDate;

    private String policyEndDate;

    private String policyIssueDate;

    private Agent agent;

    public String getPolicyNumber() {
        return policyNumber;
    }

    public void setPolicyNumber(String policyNumber) {
        this.policyNumber = policyNumber;
    }

    public String getPolicyStartDate() {
        return policyStartDate;
    }

    public void setPolicyStartDate(String policyStartDate) {
        this.policyStartDate = policyStartDate;
    }

    public String getPolicyEndDate() {
        return policyEndDate;
    }

    public void setPolicyEndDate(String policyEndDate) {
        this.policyEndDate = policyEndDate;
    }

    public String getPolicyIssueDate() {
        return policyIssueDate;
    }

    public void setPolicyIssueDate(String policyIssueDate) {
        this.policyIssueDate = policyIssueDate;
    }

    public Agent getAgent() {
        return agent;
    }

    public void setAgent(Agent agent) {
        this.agent = agent;
    }
}
```

I can able to get the value but im not able to bind the output to Html page.Please Help me .Thanks In advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind JSON object to HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571056/bind-json-object-to-html-element)

Comment: where your html ?

Comment: <tr>
 <td  style="border-right: dashed 0px #BBBBBB;"><p style="font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif; font-size:14px;color:#BBBBBB;font-weight:400;margin:0px;text-align:left;" ><VALUE-OF>row["PolicyN"]</VALUE-OF></p></td>
</tr>